# How to add another sourceSet with a mod in Minecraft Forge (Forge Gradle 3)?

Tags: gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a library made in Forge dev environment, one is in the `main` source set, containing library code; another is in the `testmod` (or any other name) source set, containing testing code that needs to be loaded as a Forge mod.

Simply adding

```
sourceSets {
    testmod {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output

        java {
            srcDir "src/testmod/java"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/testmod/resources"
        }
    }
}
```

into my `build.gradle`, Forge doesn't scan the source set and therefore doesn't load my mod. How can I make Forge load my mod?

Note that my mod is in Forge 1.14.4, and this should apply to all versions with Forge Gradle 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forge loads mod through the mods declared in the `minecraft`/`run` section. You will need to add the following lines to make Forge scan the `testmod` source set for mods.

```
minecraft {
    // ...
    runs {
        client {
            // ...
            mods {
                mainmodid {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
                testmodid {
                    source sourceSets.testmod
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            // ...
            mods {
                mainmodid {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
                testmodid {
                    source sourceSets.testmod
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `mainmodid` and `testmodid` with your own modid's. The `mainmodid` should be included in MDK as `examplemod`.

---

Although this does make Forge load your classes, it won't be able to find your `mods.toml` properly though (depends on ForgeGradle version). If you run into loading errors saying test mod isn't found in mods.toml, add the following snippet too

```
processResources {
    from(sourceSets.testmod.resources.srcDirs) {
        include "META_INF/mods.toml"
    }
}
```

Also simply adding the source set `testmod` won't add Forge and Minecraft as a dependency for it automatically. You will also to have add

```
configurations {
    testmodCompile.extendsFrom(compile)
    testmodCompileOnly.extendsFrom(compileOnly)
    testmodRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(runtimeOnly)
}
```

to make Gradle add Forge and Minecraft (the `testmod` in `testmodCompile` is the source set name, see Gradle documentation).

Comment: Also rerun `genIntellijRuns` and remove `build/`, `out/` (IDEA), `bin/` (Eclipse)